# Rotating a matrix by different angles in 2d in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, matlab-guide

I have a set of data points, and I would like to rotate each data counterclockwise in the plane by a random angle about different points in the same plane. In first try, I could rotate them counterclockwise in the plane by a certain angle about different points in the same plane:

```
x = 16:25;
y = 31:40;
% create a matrix of these points, which will be useful in future  calculations
v = [x;y];
center = [6:15;1:10];
% define a 60 degree counter-clockwise rotation matrix
theta = pi/3;       % pi/3 radians = 60 degrees
R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
% do the rotation...
vo = R*(v - center) + center;
% pick out the vectors of rotated x- and y-data
x_rotated = vo(1,:);
y_rotated = vo(2,:);
% make a plot
plot(x, y, 'k-', x_rotated, y_rotated, 'r-');
```

Then I tried to generalize it to rotate by random angels, but there is a problem which I can not solve in second code:

```
x = 16:25;
y = 31:40;
% create a matrix of these points, which will be useful in future   calculations
v = [x;y];
center = [6:15;1:10]; %center of rotation
% define random degree counter-clockwise rotation matrix
theta = pi/3*(rand(10,1)-0.5);       % prandom angle 
R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
% do the rotation...
 vo = R*(v - center) + center;
% pick out the vectors of rotated x- and y-data
x_rotated = vo(1,:);
y_rotated = vo(2,:);
% make a plot
plot(x, y, 'k-', x_rotated, y_rotated, 'r-');
```

The problem is, when I try to rotate the matrix, the rotation matrix dimension is not equal as it should. I don't know how should I create the rotation matrix in this case. 
Could anyone suggest how to solve the problem? Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is a little odd that there is no one who could answer this question

Comment: It isn't "odd".  Either no one is available to answer you right now, or people simply don't know the answer.  We answer questions here on a volunteer capacity. This is not a full-time job.  Expecting answers immediately is not the behaviour you should adopt here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a 20x2 matrix in R. To see why, consider

```
theta % is a 10x1 vector

cos(theta)  % is also going to be a 10x1 vector

[cos(theta) -sin(theta);...
 sin(theta) cos(theta)];  % is going to be a 2x2 matrix of 10x1 vectors, or a 20x2 matrix
```

What you want is to have access to every 2x2 rotation matrix. One way of doing it is

```
R1 = [cos(theta) -sin(theta)] % Create a 10x2 matrix
R2 = [sin(theta) cos(theta)] % Create a 10x2 matrix

R = cat(3,R1,R2) % Cocatenate ("paste") both matrix along the 3 dimension creating a 10x2x2 matrix

R = permute(R,[3,2,1]) % Shift dimensions so the matrix shape is 2x2x10, this will be helpful in the next step.
```

Now you need to multiply each data point by its corresponding rotation matrix. Multiplication is only defined for 2D matrices, so I don't know a better method to do this than to loop over each point.

```
for i = 1:length(v)
    vo(:,i) = R(:,:,i)*(v(:,i) - center(:,i)) + center(:,i);
end
```

Comment: Can you please expand a little about what you mean

Comment: vv=[1,2,1;1,1,-1]; phi=[0;0;0]; center=[0,0,0;0,0,0]; R1 = [cos(phi) -sin(phi)]; % Create a 10x2 matrix
R2 = [sin(phi) cos(phi)]; % Create a 10x2 matrix
R = cat(3,R1,R2) % Cocatenate ("paste") both matrix along the 3 dimension creating a 10x2x2 matrix
R = permute(R,[2,3,1]) ; vx = voo(1,:)' vy = voo(2,:)'

Comment: above comment is an example of 3 vectors. by rotating angel equal to 0. after rotation we don't expect vectors to change. but they change and becones equal to one

Comment: please run the comment and see the result

Comment: Can you please check again, because it works fine on my side. Please confirm that every rotation matrix `R(:,:,i)` is an identity matrix

Comment: Ohhhhh, I found a mistype in my answer inside the for loop, please update accordingly, I'm sure that is the problem

Comment: I expect vx=[1,2,1] and vy=[1,1,-1]. But if you run below comment, you see vx=[1;1;1] and vy=[1;1;1]. Dont you?

Comment: vv=[1,2,1;1,1,-1]; 
phi=[0;0;0]; 
center=[0,0,0;0,0,0]; 
R1 = [cos(phi) -sin(phi)]; 
R2 = [sin(phi) cos(phi)]; 
R = cat(3,R1,R2) ;
R = permute(R,[2,3,1]) ; 
for i = 1:length(vv)
    voo(:,i) = R(:,:,i)*(vv(:,1) - center(:,1)) + center(:,i);
end
vx = voo(1,:)' 
vy = voo(2,:)'

Comment: I updated the for loop in the answer, I mistype some `1`s when I mean `i`s. It should work now

Comment: I see, If you check the rotation matrix in R, you can see that the values are correct but the orientation of the matrix is not. It is because the permutation of dimensions. Change the permutations to `R=permute(R,[3 2 1])`it should fix. I'll edit the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply rotate with `imrotate`.

For example, you want to rotate 30 degrees:

```
newmat = imrotate(mat, 30, 'crop')
```

will rotate 30 degrees clockwise and keep the dimension same. To increase the size you can use `'full'` option in `imresize`

To input a random value in the rotation matrix

```
rn = rand*90; %0-90 degrees
newmat = imrotate(mat, rn, 'crop')
```

Comment: I want a random angle for each data. Not a constant angle. First part of my code is written for constant angle and it works properly

Comment: [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) says `imrotate` rotates counterclockwise, and to rotate clockwise the angle should be negative.